# PWM IC duty cycle not increasing

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, voltage-divider, duty-cycle

I was working on the UCC3895 PWM generator but am having a problem getting a complete duty cycle up to 100. I have used the following diagram for my circuit:
[image]

I wanted to use the UCC3895 to get a PWM wave so that I could give it to an H-bridge. For now, I haven't added the TL431 for the constant reference voltage and have used a simple open-loop configuration of the IC. But the results I received were not better. At a voltage of 1.16V on the EAP I was able to get a small duty cycle shown and after increasing the voltage for this pin to 5V at max, the duty cycle remained the same small amount shown below, all four outputs showed similar behavior. I want to achieve a linear duty cycle of pwm by changing the voltage at the EAP but am not able to achieve it. Kindly help me with this and correct any mistakes there.
[image]

This is the voltage on EAP after which the duty cycle didn't change:
[image]

The yellow diagram below shows the signal I received on the EAN pin while the other one is on CT.
[image]

Comment: Try to measure using scope the voltage difference between OUT A and OUT D vs pot seting.

Comment: The channel D is giving almost zero voltage , can see small spikes on the oscilloscopr, and the voltage of the OUTA is shown above. The voltage remains same after 1.16V as explained above

Comment: You can set trigger to Ch1, 1-2V, falling edge, to stabilize the display. Why is your EAN sometimes showing pulses? That seems important to fix.

Comment: Yes the EAN is showing these pulses and I myself think thats the issue because this is just the output of a buffer according to the internal diagram

Comment: @TimWilliams dont know why am I getting such as I have checked that my EAP is a DC straight line but EAN isnt. I got this type of wave as I increased the voltage on the EAP to 5V. I am not having any good simulator to simulate this as most of them are inaccurate.

Comment: @TimWilliams secondly it could be seen that my voltage on the EAN is much less than that of the EAP. As at this stage I had given 5V but am getting 1.36 at max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to help from a distance via the internet because we do not see the real circuit.

Also, do not forget that the voltage at EAP should be kept below 3.6 V for proper operation. This circuit is not a classic "PWM generator" but a phase shift PWM. What you should see at the output is almost 50% duty square wave. The only thing that is changing vs. "error voltage" is the phase shift between the outputs, not the duty cycle.

[image]

Only the phase shift is changing.

[image]

Try to build this version:

https://www.electronics-lab.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Schematic-4.pdf

Comment: Why does this circuit have the two pins of the potentiometer at EAP shorted out? Is this right or wrong? Secondly, I do not want to use the ADS and CS pins therefore I have shorted them to ground. The rest of the circuit seems to be the same as My one. Ill buy another IC and test with it to ensure the IC is working well.

Comment: In this case, the pot is working as a variable resistor. Not the best solution in this case. The  better  one is to use  VRef --->20k resistor-->50K POT---> GND.  So that we stay below 3.6V.  https://tinyurl.com/2axsmf87

Comment: so it means from 0 to 3.6 we will have an approximate phase shift from 0 to 180 degrees. The duty cycle is then related to the phase angles. Secondly the question I asked previously, I dont want to use the ADS ans CS and want to ground this, will this create any effect or not?